# MySQL Syntax error in the update statement, NodeJS(MySQL2) module

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js

I am using Node.JS along with the mysql2 module. It's basically like when I try to update a column with a JSON stingified data, I get the following error:

```
{ Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
 to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"1050":1}WHERE
 `user` = ?' at line 1
```

The stingified JSON data:

```
{"1050":1}
```

The query:

```
var sql = 'UPDATE `users` SET `furniture` = ' + 'concat(furniture,' + JSON.stringify(self.furniture) + ')' + 'WHERE `user` = ?';
```

`self.furniture` is related to something else, but I can assure you that `self.furniture` is returning that JSON data thus I get the mysql syntax error.

```
sqlMessage: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'"1050":
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is resolved using backticks along with single quotes.

```
    var sql = 'UPDATE `users` SET `furniture` = ' + `concat(furniture, '${lol}')` + 'WHERE `user` = ?';

    var lol = JSON.stringify(self.furniture)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query line says in part

```
 ...ingify(self.furniture) + ')' + 'WHERE `us...
```

It should have an extra space after the close parenthesis.

```
...ingify(self.furniture) + ') ' + 'WHERE `us...
```

Here's the thing about MySQL syntax errors: the message shows the erroneous query starting with the first character MySQL does not understand.  A good way to troubleshoot this kind of thing is to use `console.log()` to output the entire query string, then look at it carefully. You will usually find something obvious wrong.

Comment: The better thing to do, if possible, would be to use statements.

Comment: Not really related to the issue, I can't figure out what is wrong with my queries. I tried it, it still spills out the same error.